# Error 4 The type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: entity-framework-6

Já procurei várias soluções para esse erro na internet e infelizmente nada me ajudou.

Alguém pode me ajudar sobre como resolver esse erro??

> Error 4   The type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' is defined in an
>   assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Comment: Dentro do seu projeto, na parte de `References`, o Entity Framework está lá?

Comment: Sim, na class library onde se encontra o arquivo .edmx

Comment: Class Library? Você separou o projeto em uma DLL de *Models* e outra de apresentação? E a camada de apresentação tem essa referência também?

Comment: O projeto não é MVC amigo, é WebForms e está dividido em camadas. Respondendo sua pergunta, sim, porém tem mais de duas CL (camadas).

Comment: Agora está mais claro pra mim. Cada camada que faça uso de um contexto precisa ter o pacote instalado. Isso foi feito?

Comment: Tiago, já fiz esse procedimento e o Cigano tmb já sugeriu isso na resposta baixo. Cigano, tenho outros projetos estruturados da mesma forma e isso passou a acontecer apenas nesse quando atualizei o Entity para 6.1.1

Comment: Qual das DLL's devo referenciar nos outros projetos para o entity 6 EntityFramework.dll ou System.Data.Entity.dll ??

Answer (score 1):

Abra seu Package Manager Console (no menu do Visual Studio: <kbd>View</kbd> > <kbd>Other Windows</kbd> > <kbd>Package Manager Console</kbd>) e digite o comando:

> Update-Package –reinstall EntityFramework

Comment: Nada amigo, já desinstalei e reinstalei o Entity e o problema continua. Mas mesmo assim obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

No seu projeto:

1. Botão direito em <kbd>References</kbd> > <kbd>Add Reference ...</kbd>
2. Escolha a aba <kbd>Browse</kbd> clique no botão de mesmo nome <kbd>Browse</kbd>
3. Procure na **Pasta do seu projeto** > `packages` > `EntityFramework.X.XX.` > `lib`
4. Escolha `EntityFramework.dll`
5. Clique `OK`

Obs: talvez na pasta lib tenha pastas referente a versão do DotNet (Escolha a apropriada para seu projeto) e depois a DLL `EntityFramework.dll`.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950638/the-referenced-component-entityframework-could-not-be-found/12488405#12488405